# Why extracted .app file appears in Finder 3.1 Mb and in bash only 102 bytes?

Tags: macos, permission, filesystem, file-sharing, archive

I extracted atMonitor using `Archive Utility` and `The Unarchiver` and in both cases it appears in the Finder as 3.1Mb and in bash only 102 bytes. Strange is that I can execute it and I can look in the package content both in Terminal and in Finder and the files inside appears **not to be a symlinks**.

The Problem is that I can't copy the `.app` file through shared folder from another computer.

What is the problem with it?

## Update:

in Finder:

[image: in Finder]

in Terminal:

[image: in Terminal]

Comment: Use Finder to Show Package Contents and see what is in it

Comment: I already noticed: I can look in the package content both in Terminal and in Finder and the files inside appears not to be a symlinks.

Comment: Can you please add links to some screenshots to prevent people from having to guess too much?

Comment: updated. but what are the screenshots helpful for? it is the same I described

Comment: You got the answer below already. The relevant part is the little `d` in the first column of the Terminal screenshot. The screenshots helped in making sure that there isn't anything else amiss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.app files are really just folders, but applications (like finder) see them differently and calculate the size of the contents of the folder.

Empty folders have the size of 68 bytes, non-empty folders are 102 bytes or bigger.
All my folders and .apps are 102 bytes since they contain only 1 sub-folder.

Comment: Regarding 68 byte and 102 byte folder sizes, the size depends on the number of files in the folder.  Most apps only have a single "Contents/" subfolder, so it will appear as 102 bytes.  But, it is not necessarily always true.  (In the screen shot, see the "3" in the left column?  That is the number of "files" in that directory.  Every directory has at least two files (ls -lFa shows "." and ".."), and each one of them takes up 34 bytes.  Also, in the screenshot, notice "." has a size of 170, with 5 files.  Same principle.

Comment: @static As for why they are so small—a Unix directory is not its contents, but rather a, well, *directory* of its contents—a machine-readable listing of filenames and where to find them on disk.  The file contents themselves (and permissions, etc.) are not contained within the folder.

Comment: @zigg: yep, inodes...